# How to embed subtitles to .Mov files for Quicktime?

Tags: quicktime, subtitles

I couldn't find a free way to do it, is there a way to embed subtitles free, without watermarks or time limitation ? I should not convert the video to any format, last format must be .mov, also the quality must not change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this program does't watermark your video but give it a try. Quality shall not be affected.

http://software-download.name/2012/subtitle-mov-video/